# Library not fount -lPods

Tags: ios, iphone

I got follwing errro in my application.

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/idev/Desktop/Swami/Project/Sources/Xcode/chronicle/chronicle/Vendor/openssl-1.0.1e/lib'
ld: library not found for -lPods
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

[image: screenshot linker output]

Please help me...

Comment: That warning is self explanatory shows that lib directory not found which you added or added by xcode in library search path of project.

Comment: but library search path is empty...

Comment: Do one thing search for openssl-1.0.1e in your project and check where it is added.

Answer (score 2):

You need to open ".xcworkspace" instead of ".xcodeproj". the .xcworkspace is generated when you install pod on the project.

Comment: is the problem still occur? If so can you check your podfile if it has "pod 'OpenSSL', '~> 1.0.1'" or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Xcode is not able to find the library, and hence the library error. Click on the project target, go to build settings, under search paths -> frameworks search paths, delete paths. You may have moved your desktop folder along with the library.

Answer (score 0):

It seems project has been using http://cocoapods.org/. and that files are missing from your project.

You cant just download it from git. You need to install it from cocoapods.

you may follow Introduction to http://www.raywenderlich.com/64546/introduction-to-cocoapods-2 Tutorial